# TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got float)

Tags: python, typeerror, spacy

I am working on a code for aspect extraction. I was getting the following error. can anyone help me resolve this ?

aspect_terms = []
for review in nlp.pipe(df2.review):
chunks = [(chunk.root.text) for chunk in review.noun_chunks if chunk.root.pos_ == 'NOUN']
aspect_terms.append(''.join(chunks))

TypeError: `Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got float).`

Comment: Not without code

Comment: Please format your code (Ctrl+K). Help us help you

Comment: I am new to this site. still learning.

Comment: So learn something new :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covert `chunk.root.text` to a string during list comprehension. `.join` requires strings in the iterable.

```
aspect_terms = [] 
for review in nlp.pipe(df2.review):
    chunks = [str(chunk.root.text) for chunk in review.noun_chunks if chunk.root.pos_ == 'NOUN']
    aspect_terms.append(''.join(chunks))
```

Comment: Better to use a generator expression and not list comprehension (`chunks = (str(chunk.root.text) for chunk in review.noun_chunks if chunk.root.pos_ == 'NOUN')`)

Comment: Now I see that this in the OP's question. Sorry

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You're not wrong though :)